# python Tkinter : How do i load status bar with "Work in progress" before calling another function running in different thread

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, tkinter

I am really new to python. In my below program i want to update the status in status bar to "Work in progress" before the mywork function is called. But as soon as i click on button GUI freezes and i am not able to see the status to "Work in progress". i want to see the "Work in progress" status as soon as  i click the button.

```
from tkinter import *
import threading
import time

def check2():    
    global status
    while status=="continue":
        print("**** Working in Progres ...")
        time.sleep(3)
    print("***** Work is Completed *****")
    statusbar["text"] = "Work is Completed"

def mywork():

    global status
    global t
    for i in range(3):
        print(i)
        time.sleep(2)
        print('Hello')
    status = "stop"


def on_click():

    global status
    status = "continue"
    statusbar["text"] = "Work in Progress"
    t = threading.Thread(target=mywork)
    statusbar["text"] = "Work in Progress"
    t.start()
    check2()
    t.join()


window=Tk()

b16 = Button(window,text='Disconnect',command=on_click)

b16.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=10, pady=10)

b16.config(height='1',width='15')

statusbar = Label(window,text="IDLE",bd=3,relief=SUNKEN,font='Helvetica 9 bold')

statusbar.grid(row=3,column=0,columnspan=4,rowspan=2)

statusbar.config(width="80",anchor="w")


window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please fix the formatting of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are better ways to do this, but essentially the problem is that the on_click() function does not complete until the t.join() completes. This causes the button to block the GUI until the thread completes. Here is a way to modify the solution to make it work as you expect.

```
from tkinter import *
import threading
import time

def check2():
    global status

    while status=="continue":
        print("**** Working in Progres ...")
        time.sleep(3)
    print("***** Work is Completed *****")
    statusbar["text"] = "Work is Completed"

def mywork():
    global status
    global t
    for i in range(3):
        print(i)
        time.sleep(2)
        print('Hello')
    status = "stop"

def on_click():
    global status
    status = "continue"
    statusbar["text"] = "Work in Progress"
    t = threading.Thread(target=mywork)
    statusbar["text"] = "Work in Progress"
    # Schedule the start of the thread outside of the on_click event.
    statusbar.after(10, lambda: start_thread(t))

def start_thread(t):
    t.start()
    check2()
    t.join()

window=Tk()
b16 = Button(window,text='Disconnect',command=on_click)
b16.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=10, pady=10)
b16.config(height='1',width='15')
statusbar = Label(window,text="IDLE",bd=3,relief=SUNKEN,font='Helvetica 9 bold')
statusbar.grid(row=3,column=0,columnspan=4,rowspan=2)
statusbar.config(width="80",anchor="w")
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer.. it works fine in this case . But if the function mywork() has a very time consuming task to be done at the back end instead of just printing the value like in upper case, the window still freezes. 

sry my understanding of multi threading is very noob but i believe the control to another function check() will pass only if time.sleep() is called . ? am i correct in assuming that ?  so if the function has big task to perform before sleep is called than ... will it not hang again ?